# How to get the total count of rows AND the count based on the distinct values of another column in the table

Tags: sql, count

Suppose we have the table:

```
+----------+------------+
| order_id | order_type |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | classsic   |
+----------+------------+
| 2        | classic    |
+----------+------------+
| 3        | urgent     |
+----------+------------+
| 4        | urgent     |
+----------+------------+
| 5        | canceled   |
+----------+------------+
| 6        | canceled   |
+----------+------------+
| 7        | classic    |
+----------+------------+
```

and it is requested to get the total count of all orders as well as the count of orders for each order_type.

the returned result  supposed to be similar to:

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| total | classic | urgent | canceled |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| 7     | 3       | 2      | 2        |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

which sql statement would get us the above result?

Comment: No need for a GROUP BY here. Use case expressions to do conditional counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select count(*) total,
       count(case when order_type = 'classic' then 1 end) classic,           
       count(case when order_type = 'urgent ' then 1 end) urgent ,
       count(case when order_type = 'canceled ' then 1 end) canceled 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the desired output. More about `PIVOT` operator [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
declare @tbl as table(
    order_id int
    ,order_type varchar(15)
)


insert into @tbl values (1, 'classic')
insert into @tbl values (2, 'classic')
insert into @tbl values (3, 'urgent')
insert into @tbl values (4, 'urgent')
insert into @tbl values (5, 'canceled')
insert into @tbl values (6, 'canceled')
insert into @tbl values (7, 'classic')


SELECT
    classic + urgent + canceled AS Total
    ,classic
    ,urgent
    ,canceled
FROM (
    SELECT order_id, order_type from @tbl   
) tbl
PIVOT(
    COUNT(order_id) FOR order_type IN (classic, urgent, canceled)
) pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with `Case` expression if you don't wont go `Dynamic` or `Pivot`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN order_type = 'classic'
                    OR order_type = 'classsic'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) classic,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN order_type = ' urgent '
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) urgent,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN order_type = 'canceled'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) canceled
FROM <table_name>;
```

**Result :**

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| total | classic | urgent | canceled |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| 7     | 3       | 2      | 2        |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```